# Accessing data returned from promise in Redux

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, redux, promise

I'm trying to access the data of the first dataElement in the array. How can I reach it? I want to console.log it's name.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Submit extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const programStage = this.props.getProgramStage();

        if (programStage !== null) {
            console.log('Stage loaded...');
        }

        console.log(this.props.getForm());
    }

    render() {
        return <div />;
    }
}

export default Submit;
```

[How the console looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uxyC.png)

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the pic, the promise is resolved. Hence you should be able to access the data like :

```
this.props.getForm().then((data) => console.log(data[0].name))
```

Comment: It's from the this.props.getForm() that gives the output. Tried `const getForm = this.props.getForm();
      getForm.then(data => console.log(data[0]));`but it did not work

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Hmm, got an unhandled rejection. Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data[0].name')

Comment: That means, the promise is not returned by that method during that particular phase. Would need parent component code to debug more.
But IMO as a thumb rule, keep the components stateless as much as possible. If the parent component creates the promise, it should be the one resolving the same and giving the required data to the child. Child component ideally should be stateless and not be knowing about how the data is being fetched. Speaking from clear separation of concerns PoV

Comment: Added form as InitialState in Reducer. It does work now. Not entirely sure why.

Comment: It works because by default initial state is `undefined` and that what gets passed as prop initially. I am guessing at some later point of time you are firing an action that updates the state with the promise object.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the return type of the call `getForm()` is a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (according to the output). You would need to append a handler via the `then` method of the promise to actually get the value you are looking for.

E.g.

```
componentDidMount() {
  ...

  this.props.getForm().then(result => console.log(result))
}
```